# Adding 'controls' to Fabricator 'UI Toolkit'

Tags: handlebars.js, fabricator, fabricator-assemble

I'm building a style guide using [Fabricator](http://fbrctr.github.io/), and [the docs](http://fbrctr.github.io/getting-started/working-with-fabricator.html#controls) seem to indicate that I should be able to add 'controls' to let the users toggle visibility on various sections.

By default, Fabricator builds come with 3 main toggles: `labels`, `notes`, and `code`. I want to add a 4th toggle that I'm calling `styles`.

The relevant sections of the `fabricator.js` file look like this:

```
/**
 * Default options
 * @type {Object}
 */
fabricator.options = {
  toggles: {
    labels: true,
    notes: true,
    code: false,
    styles: true,
  },
  menu: true,
  mq: '(min-width: 60em)',
};
```

&

```
/**
 * Handler for preview and code toggles
 * @return {Object} fabricator
 */
fabricator.allItemsToggles = () => {

  const itemCache = {
    labels: document.querySelectorAll('[data-f-toggle="labels"]'),
    notes: document.querySelectorAll('[data-f-toggle="notes"]'),
    code: document.querySelectorAll('[data-f-toggle="code"]'),
    styles: document.querySelectorAll('[data-f-toggle="styles"]'),
  };
}
```

As you can see, I've added my `styles` toggle to the `fabricator.options` object and to the itemCache object matching the formatting to the existing elements.

I've also added new `styles` sections to the controls and content partials:

`f-item-controls.html`

```
{{!-- this is part of the default build --}}
{{#if notes}}
<span class="f-control f-icon" data-f-toggle-control="notes" title="Toggle Notes">
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="#f-icon-notes" />
    </svg>
</span>
{{/if}}

{{!-- this is my matching addition --}}
{{#if styles}}
<span class="f-control f-icon" data-f-toggle-control="styles" title="Toggle Styles">
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="#f-icon-styles" />
    </svg>
</span>
{{/if}}
```

`f-item-content.html`

```
{{!-- this is part of the default build --}}
{{#if notes}}
<div class="f-item-notes" data-f-toggle="notes">
    {{{notes}}}
</div>
{{/if}}

{{!-- this is my matching addition --}}    
{{#if styles}}
<div class="f-item-styles" data-f-toggle="styles">
    {{{styles}}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Finally, just so I have content to work with, I added some 'front-matter' data that my button component could render:

```
---
notes: |
  These are notes written in `markdown`
styles: |
  These are styles written in `markdown`
---
```

The `notes` (part of the default build) render and toggle correctly; the `styles` don't render at all. If I remove the {{#if}} conditions around the `styles` blocks, then the `control` icon and corresponding `content` `<div>` are generated, but the actual `style` text is still missing.

I've reached out to Luke Askew (the creator of Fabricator) asking for clarity, but I haven't heard back from him yet. In the meantime, I'm hoping someone in the SO community might be able to help me understand how this works so that I can continue my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## update

The author (@lukeaskew) responded to my email inquiry and indicated that all 'front-matter' data gets packed up into `data` (accessible as `{{data}}` or `{{{data}}}`), and to access or check the 'styles' data I was initially trying to add, I could simply enter `{{{data.styles}}}` in my f-item-contents & f-item-controls files.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason or if you want a truly independent data section, you can follow the instructions as I've laid out below.

## original answer body

I figured out how to add **[control](http://fbrctr.github.io/getting-started/working-with-fabricator.html#controls)** (content toggles) to Fabricator - hopefully this will help someone else.

For starters, I'm not certain, but I suspect that `styles` (the name I gave to my custom control) may be a reserved word, because having it in the `fabricator.js` file periodically causes the gulp task to stop running/fail. Unfortunately, (as of this posting) there's still no indication in the [docs](http://fbrctr.github.io/building-a-toolkit/data.html#reserved-words) what the reserved words are other than that there's a list of reserved words.

To add a `control`, in addition to the steps indicated in my question, you also need to modify the `node_module` that assembles the site from the `src` folder.

The file is located in your Fabricator folder at `node_modules/fabricator-assemble/index.js` and you'll need to modify the following section (LINE ~332), replacing 'NEW_TOGGLE_NAME' with the name of your new control (same name you used in the sections mentioned in my question):

```
// capture meta data for the material
if (!isSubCollection) {
  assembly.materials[collection].items[key] = {
    name: toTitleCase(id),
    notes: (fileMatter.data.notes) ? md.render(fileMatter.data.notes) : '',

    NEW_TOGGLE_NAME: (fileMatter.data.NEW_TOGGLE_NAME) ? md.render(fileMatter.data.NEW_TOGGLE_NAME) : '',

    data: localData
  };
} else {
  assembly.materials[parent].items[collection].items[key] = {
    name: toTitleCase(id.split('.')[1]),
    notes: (fileMatter.data.notes) ? md.render(fileMatter.data.notes) : '',

    NEW_TOGGLE_NAME: (fileMatter.data.NEW_TOGGLE_NAME) ? md.render(fileMatter.data.NEW_TOGGLE_NAME) : '',

    data: localData
  };
}
```